# How to maintain a database structure when there are multiple instance of the DB?

Tags: database, automatic-update

I've created an application that can create and update documents. A document is a relational database (it's a SQLite database).

I'm planning to update the structure of the database (add fields, add relations, add tables)

The database stores the `database_version` in itself. I plan to embed update SQL scripts into the software and apply them depending on the version of the loaded database. Note I will never update or remove tables or fields as I want full retro-compatibility

Is it a good solution or is there a better one?

Comment: What language is your application? Many languages have tools specifically for this use case

Comment: I'm using C# (.Net 4.6.1)

Comment: This was closed as off topic, but it may be what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997046/an-orm-for-sqlite-net-for-small-applications

Answer (score 1):

You are basically home-rolling a database migration tool. While the approach is sound, I'm hesitant to propose that you write this yourself. There are a number of tools out there that can handle this for you that are battle-hardened and have been tested thoroughly across hundreds (if not thousands) of applications. I advise you to look into those.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you how this is done where I work:

1. We develop our database (*Firebird*) with an IDE (*IB Expert*).
2. When we come to a point where the the changes are considered complete, we create a structural difference script with the IDE by providing the old and the new database.
3. We manually extend the diff script with DML statements, if needed.
4. Then, a new version of our client application is released. On its startup, it checks the database version (saved in the database) and - if the version is older - it applies the script to the database. When the script was applied successfully, the database version in the database is updated.

This relies completely on the capabilities of our database IDE. *SQLite* provides a tool [sqldiff.exe](https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html) for diffing two databases.